# Placing image above sidebar next to slider on frontpage

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently trying to place a image above the sidebar next to the slider, would this be done with adding a wrap. the site is at www.dabbpad.com
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDjg.jpg)
This is a photo of the site layout, would I need to wrap the slider in a new div or would the 2 be in the same div? I know CSS tweaks might need to be done to get this task done. can someone assist with this

Comment: This really isn't possible to answer well without your current markup.  Please show your markup that contains the slideshow and contents down the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the explanation :

remove the float:none from this div.meteor-slides to float:left as shown in image [image]

And below the slider div that is below the div having class as .meteor-slides add this div with class .my_right_section see below image :

[image]